# Why with using setTimeout() does an error "This add-in is not responding" still occur?

Tags: office-js

For a long-running add-in operation I use `setTimeout()` as recommended in [Resource limits and performance optimization for Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization) (section "Design and implementation techniques"):

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var i = 0;
    ...
    prgText.setTotal(LIMIT);
    setTimeout(writing, PAUSE);
    return context.sync();

    function writing() {
        var row = tblText.container.insertRow(i + 1);
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "text";
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = i++;
        prgText.setProgress(i);
        if (i < LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(writing, PAUSE);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

But the error still occurs:

[image: screenshot]

How to change the example so that the error does not occur? And why this warning is called an error?

Please note that the question is not about how to speed up the script.

The full example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/costashu/WordTimeoutAddIn)

Comment: Could you provide the full code for this word.run? I'm not clear what you're doing here and (at the moment) it looks like you're pausing before you sync and therefore never actually syncing.

Comment: Full code - https://github.com/costashu/WordTimeoutAddIn

Comment: 10 seconds is a rather long time to wait before updating your progress bar. Why so long?

Comment: The progress bar is updated an every second regularly and smoothly: `const PAUSE = 0;`. Run the example from GiHub, please.

Comment: Marс, do you have any advice how to solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to work out the exact code changes here but I can tell you the problem is how you're inserting rows. This requires the browser to calculate layout/rendering each time. Once you get enough rows in play execution starts blocking long enough to get flagged as unresponsive. And to be honest, I can't think of a reason why you'd _ever_ want to render 5-10k rows in a single table.

Comment: I hope you'll find the time to run the example and make sure that there are no delays due to rendering. A very large table is needed for a dictionary of document with million characters, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure that many rows will ever work as you expect. I think you need to reconsider the user scenario here. Expecting a user to read 10k rows in a 400px wide task pane  is simply not realistic.

Comment: They works. You may check. But question about that strange error, which called "warning", or warning, which called "error". It seems to me that the developers should reconsider this "error".

Comment: It's a time out that is happening because you are blocking for such an extended period of time to handle rendering. This scenario (injection of thousands of rows) is not supported.

Comment: Excuse me, Marc, but nothing is locked even for a second, progress is constantly increasing on progress bar. You just need to run once an example from Github to make sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason appears to be that the timeout is set to zero milliseconds. So if the loop is long enough then the add-in will hang.

The best solution is probably to extract your logic from the Word.run statement as much as possible. For example, you could construct the table entries before calling Word.run, then simply set many rows of values in a single call instead of calling insertRow many times repeatedly.